# How can I apply this style in Django? (radio type)

Tags: html, css, django, web

How can I apply this style in Django? 
just one class i can apply in django but double class i cant do that.

Django 2.1, python 3.7

I want use this css style https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Zk2Pz

```
<div class="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-default">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
            <label for="radio1">First Option default</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" checked/>
            <label for="radio2">Second Option primary</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" />
            <label for="radio3">Third Option success</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-danger">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" />
            <label for="radio4">Fourth Option danger</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-warning">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio5" />
            <label for="radio5">Fifth Option warning</label>
        </div>
        <div class="funkyradio-info">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio6" />
            <label for="radio6">Sixth Option info</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want apply this part, 
and my django form class is

```
class DataUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataUpload
        fields =('Type', 'Kind', 'description', 'document',)
        widgets = {
            'Type': forms.RadioSelect(attrs = {'class' : 'funkyradio funkyradio-default'}),
            'Kind': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

but it isn't work

I want radio form using that css

Comment: You need to build your own widget to get the outside divs - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are looking for, One solution is to get more granular when rendering your form in the template.

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) provide directions.

Below is one way you can do achieve your desired result based on the documentation:

In your **forms.py**, you could do something like this:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):

    choices=(('Value1', 'Choice1'), 
             ('Value2', 'Choice2'), 
             ('Value3', 'Choice3')
             ..
            )

    options = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=choices)
```

Access your form in the **views.py**:

```
def my_view(request):
    # your code here

    return render(request, 'your_app/template.html', form=TestForm())
```

Then in your template, **template.html** file:

```
<form action='/place_url_here', method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="funkyradio">
        {% for radio in form.options %}
            <div class="funky-{{ radio.choice_label }}">
                {{ radio.tag }}
                <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">{{ radio.choice_label }}</label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```

Based on the above, you can modify the styles to get your desired results.

Hope that helps. Good Luck.